# If a YouTube channel gets banned, does the associated Gmail account get banned also?

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account, google-adsense, copyright

I have a YouTube channel that recently got its first ever copyright violation.

This YouTube account is linked to my main Gmail account with thousands of emails.

My question is simple: if the YouTube channel gets banned for whatever reason, am I also going to lose the Gmail account / the whole Google account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you will not lose your Gmail account. But you will not be able to access your associated YouTube channels.

Comment: @serenesat will I be able to surf or explore youtube channels or any song?